# Warum wird "okay" als Adverb klassifiziert?

Tags: word-classes

Sowohl [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/okay#2) als auch der [Rechtschreibduden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/okay_abgemacht_einverstanden) listen "okay" in der Bedeutung "einverstanden / zugegeben / genug davon" als Adverb. Gemeint ist das "okay" wie in

> Okay, kein Problem. // Ok, Boomer // Er sitzt gerade im Auto, aber okay, man könne ihn schon fragen.

und nicht das Adjektiv wie in

> Die Kekse sind OK.

Was mich an der Klassifikation stört, ist

1. Ok wird immer wie ein Einschub gesprochen. Von der Satzmelodie her verhält es sich meiner Meinung nach viel mehr wie eine Interjektion, ganz ähnlich wie z.B. "ach".
2. Ok ist nicht vorfeldfähig. Einen Satz wie

> - Ok(,) können wir das machen.

halte ich, mit oder ohne Komma, für nicht grammatikalisch. (Außer natürlich als "Okay können wir das machen, aber perfekt nicht." mit "okay" als Adjektiv)

3. Wenn man "Ok" immer als Einschub sieht, ist es sogar gar nicht möglich, "Ok" adverbial zu nutzen.

Was sind also Gründe, "OK" als Adverb und nicht etwa als Interjektion oder Partikel zu sehen?
Oder ist es einfach nur da, weil es nirgendswo sonst so recht reinpasst? Schließlich heißt es in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Klassifizierung_von_Adverbien) z.B.

> [Für Adverbien] ergibt sich soweit eine uneinheitliche Restklasse von Wörtern, die lediglich gemeinsam haben, dass sie keiner anderen Kategorie eindeutig zugeordnet werden können.

Comment: Adverbien im Deutschen stellen (auch) ein Sammelbecken für "passt nirgends richtig rein" dar, wie du richtig erkannt hast. Der Adverbialcharakter wird aber klar, wenn man Sätze wie "Wie lief deine Prüfung?" - "Die Prüfung lief ganz OK" betrachtet.

Comment: @tofro: das stimmt, aber das zeigt doch nur, daß "OK" *auch* als Adverb verwendet werden kann. Ich sehe den grundsätzlichen Unterschied zwischen zB "OK und "ach" in "OK, wir können ihn fragen" und "Habe nun, ach, ... durchaus studieret" nicht - und "ach" betrachtet man auch nicht als Adverb.

Comment: *ach* ist eine Interjektion und kann nur als solche verwendet werden. Ein adverbialer Gabrauch (*Die Prüfung ist ach gelaufen*) kommt nicht in Frage. In "OK, wir können in fragen" ist *OK* ein Antwortpartikel, kein Adverb. In meinem Beispiel sehr wohl.

Comment: "Lass uns heute die Wand streichen!"/"Ich hab' keine Farbe - wenn Du welche mitbringst …?"/"OK, können wir das machen?" würde schon gehen, oder?

Comment: @tofro: Das ist aber nicht Bedeutung 2 "einverstanden", sondern Bedeutung 1 "annehmbar". Dieses "OK" wird als Adjektiv klassifiziert, und das macht auch Sinn. "Antwortpartikel" finde ich auch gut, aber halt nicht "Adverb".

Comment: @userunknown Ja natürlich, aber das wäre als Frage ja ein Verberstsatz und OK ist auch nicht im Vorfeld.

Comment: Nun, es ist eben so, dass "okay" mehrere Bedeutungen angenommen hat, eine davon ist adverbial. Daher ist "okay" (meistens, manche Wörterbücher zählen auch "Adjektiv, Interjektion, Adverb, Partikel" auf)) als Adverb klassifiziert. "Ach" ist eben nur eine Interjektion, kann daher auch niucht als Adverb klassifiziert werden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt Adverbien, die vor dem Gesamtsatz (Verbzweitsatz) stehen können, vgl.: "Trotzdem, wir können das nicht machen." Das, zusammen mit Sätzen wie "Es lief ok" könnte die Begründung für die Einstufung als Adverb liefern.

Trotzdem, wenn es nicht im Vorfeld stehen kann, ist es nach herkömmlichen Definitionen kein Adverb. Die Eigenschaften von "ok" passen also insgesamt nicht genau in irgendeine der normalen Wortarten. Ich würde den Schluss ziehen, dass du im Grundsatz recht hast mit deinem Einwand. Vielleicht sollte man dann auch sagen, "ok" ist mehrdeutig zwischen einem Adverb und was anderem. Denn ich kriege "Ok war es schon, aber nicht begeisternd" - nur in der Bedeutung von "einverstanden" geht "ok" in dieser Position nicht. Da kommt man auf eine Klasse von Wörtern, wie "ok, einverstanden, ach-komm..." die man Diskursmarker nennt; nur sind sich die Leute wohl uneinig, wie sie sich zu den klassischen Wortarten verhalten (weil sie eben außerhalb des Satzes stehen). Da müsste ich nochmal mehr nachlesen. Gute Frage!